# Analytical solution to $f''(x)-(ax+b)f(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, homogeneous-equation

I am trying to solve the following ODE:

$$f''(x)-(ax+b)f(x)=0 \tag1$$

To obtain the expression for $f(x)$, I have tried to use the method described in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250891739_Solving_second-order_differential_equations_with_variable_coefficients) science article.
According to that method, the general solution to equation $(1)$ is

$$f(x)= \sum _{k=0}^{\inf}g_{_k}(x) \tag2$$
where

$$g_{_0} (x)= 1$$
$$g_{_1}(x)=\int_0^x (x-t)\Big((at+b)g_{_0}\Big)dt$$
$$g_{_2}(x)=\int_0^x (x-t)\Big((at+b)g_{_1}(t)\Big)dt\tag3$$
$$...$$
$$g_{_k}(x)=\int_0^x (x-t)\Big((at+b)g_{_{k-1}}(t)\Big)dt$$
I tried to write $g_{_1}(x)$, $g_{_2}(x)$ and $g_{_3}(x)$ in a way where a pattern could occur:

$$g_{_1}(x)= {1+3\over 2}{a\over 3!}x^3 + {b\over2!}x^2$$
$$g_{_2}(x)= {1+3\over 2}{3+5\over 2}{a^2\over 6!}x^6 + \Bigg({1\over 5!} + {1\over 6!}\Bigg)abx^5+{{b^2 \over 4!} x^4} \tag4$$

$$g_{_3}(x)= {1+3\over 2}{3+5\over 2}{6+8\over 2} {a^3\over 9!}x^9 + {1+3\over 2}{3+5\over 2} {a^2 b\over 8!}x^8
+ \Bigg( {{6!}\over{5!}} + {{5!}\over{5!}}\Bigg) {a^2 b\over 8!}x^8 +
  \Bigg( {{5!}\over{5!}} + {{5!}\over{6!}}\Bigg){a {b^2}\over 7!}x^7+
  {6+4\over 2}{a {b^2}\over 7!}x^7 + {{b^3 \over 6!} x^6}$$

It can be seen in expressions $(4)$ that I failed to do that. I was not able to find the pattern.

My question is: If $f(x)$ is the general solution to equation $(1)$, what is its exact analytical expression?

Comment: This is a shifted and scaled version of the Airy equation. You get something looking like a solution using the Laplace transform, one can compute or look up the power series expansion centered at $x_0=-b/a$ or use the Airy functions as black box.

Comment: Learn about the Airy differential equation and its solutions.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function

Comment: This can be expressed as Airy equation.